# Swift/SwiftUI toolbar .principal creates awkward gap between toolbar and content

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, toolbar

I was wondering why there was a strange gap between my toolbar and the content of the view and have realised it is caused by the .principal placement of items in the toolbar. Any other placement doesn't cause the same gap to occur.

In the toolbar, I want one item to be centred and another two on each side in the corner. I just don't want that strange gap.

```
struct AnotherTest: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello, World!")
                Spacer()
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    Text("testing")
                }
            }
            
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Didi you try `.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)`?

Comment: I had not... but that has worked, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline) as per @HunterLion